# Using a KnockoutJS template binding with jQuery UI confirmation dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

How would I go about using a jQuery UI dialog to confirm whether they want to delete a row from a a list within a KnockoutJS template?

As I see it, the Knockout demos show a template which renders each row in a grid.
The delete button calls the `viewModel.remove()` function passing in the object of the row to delete.  Inside the `remove()` function, `this.Gifts.Remove()` is called with the data passed into the function as a parameter.

My problem is that I want to display a jQuery dialog to ask for confirmation of whether a row should be deleted.  JQuery dialog works on the basis of a setup function which sets up the dialog and its delete function beforehand.

When I click on my delete link in the template, it opens the dialog ok, but how do I pass the template data into the dialog delete function, as it is now completely decoupled from the template mechanism?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am assuming that the dialog is from jQuery UI.  If so, then you your remove would look something like this:

```
removeItem: function(item) {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete item": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                viewModel.items.remove(item);
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So, the "Delete item" button would close the dialog and also remove your item from your observableArray.

Working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/CLxsV/

Edit: better sample using bindings here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WpnTU/

Comment: Is there any way to test that the dialog method was called with the correct parameters?

It would be to be able to test the interactions between the methods on the model and the jQuery UI. For example, to ensure that the buttons were bound correctly, that modal was true, etc. Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest better use custom knockout binding like in this sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436160/mvc-knockout-js-inside-jquery-dialog

Comment: @VikciaR updated this question and the one that you linked with a version that uses bindings both for the wire up and opening/closing.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer thanks for complete sample using custom bindings.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer Your second example (http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WpnTU/) has an interesting use of this and self in the viewModel. Was this deliberate? If so, why?

Comment: Product and ViewModel are both using a different technique (`self` vs. binding to `this`) to ensure that `this` is correct. I doubt that it was deliberate, as I wouldn't normally mix the two, but either is valid.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer when using new Knockout version (2.3.0) this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WpnTU/ causes knockout error "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element". Could you please suggest what can be done to fix it?

Comment: jQuery UI moves the dialog to the bottom of the page and then Knockout's initial pass of binding all the elements hits it again. You can either initialize the widget in a setTimeout like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WpnTU/ or it would work properly if you called `ko.applyBindings(yourViewModel, someElement)`, as jQuery UI moves it to be the last element and it would not get bound if the bindings were scoped to a certain root element (other than body).

Comment: @RPNiemeyer thanks, it works perfectly

I would suggest adding         
if (!$(element).is(':data(dialog)')) return;

at the begining of update method of openDialog binding, so it won't try to close dialog that wasn't initialized yet